# Scrolling up when resizing colorbox

Tags: jquery, scroll, colorbox

First, sorry if I don't use correct words, but my english is not the best, and my problem is kind of complicated to explain, for me.

So, I am using Colorbox from JQuery, and I display a long content in the colorbox, so there is a scrollbar on the windows (but not the colorbox). But I dynamically add content to the colorbox, so I have to resize the colorbox. The problem is that when I resize the colorbox, the all window is scrolling up to the top of the colorbox, and I would just like the content to be added, but the position of the user shouldn't change.

So is it possible the resize a colorbox without beeing bring back to the top of the page ? 
(If you don't understand anything I said, tell me, and I will try my best to make me understanable)

Thanks !!

Comment: ColorBox is not from Jquery.  It is a Jquery plugin. Colorbox was developed and is maintained by Jack Moore @ [colorpowered.com](http://www.colorpowered.com). (I am not affiliated with him.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the new content is getting added at the end of the div, I think you could just capture the scroll position before content is added:

```
var scrollposition = $("#yourcontentdiv").scrollTop();

// add content here

$("#yourcontentdiv").scrollTop(scrollposition);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Your solution is very good, and this would be exactly what I need ! But it doesn't seem to be working, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I did this : 
scrollposition = $("#mydiv").scrollTop();
$.fn.colorbox.resize();
$("#mydiv").scrollTop(scrollposition);
The name isn't wrong, because I can access it for anything else.But when I try to get the scrollTop of the footer, I still get 0, and it shouldn't be that, so maybe scrollTop isn't working so I am going to search about that. (I tried $('#mydiv').scrollTop(300), and it doesn't work...)